# Power BI gateway issue

Tags: powerbi

[image: Power BI gateway issue]

Hey guys, need help in resolving this gateway issue. Any suggestions how i can fix this ? Let me know if you need more information. "I have attached the picture "

Comment: It looks like the data source in that cluster hasn't had credentials provided to access your source server, although it's hard to be sure because that part is cropped from the image.

Comment: no, the data source credentials are provided for the two data sources  "172.16.0.13" and "New data source" as you can see below the cluster "Cluid_datawarehouse" in the picture. So the amber alert is coming up next to the cluster "Cluid_datawarehouse". I need help with that